# how to work with actual hard drive when mirror drive stop working linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, mirror

i have linux/Ubuntu server 2 hard drives mirror with raid. unfortunately one partition is having EXT-fs4 error (/dev/md2) .. aborting journel frequently.. after reboot it fixes but happens again..

what should be done when mirror drive stop working? can i use actual hard drive sda sdb when it does not work?

Please advise!

Thanks

Comment: can you boot into single user mode and try to break the mirror ?  mount the fstab from the good disk and reboot?

Comment: What is the exact storage layout involved? Can you [edit] your post to include the output of running `lsblk` on the affected system?